# munin fw_conntrack going bananas after dist upgrade to debian wheezy

Tags: linux, debian-squeeze, munin, debian-wheezy

after i upgrade from squeezy to wheezy munin began doing sth weird.
it seams as if it only keeps adding the numbers and does not show the current value but only the cumulative values...

by the dist-upgrade munin was upgraded from 1.4.x to 2.0.x

see attached graph: http://unbenannter-ordner.de/stuff/33b5ecddf535a67c087819ce6a847e41.png

any idea what causes this?
all other graphs look fine...

Comment: i already delted the rdm files but munin continues to plot like before

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the same behavior here, and I think it's a problem in the `fw_conntrack` script. It's reading the data from `/proc/net/ip_conntrack`, which does contain those entries (check with `cat /proc/net/ip_conntrack | grep ESTABLISHED`).

But you'll notice that most of them are marked as "UNREPLIED" - which according to http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/FAQ/netfilter-faq-3.html#ss3.17 is normal, they just keep them around until they run out of space and then overwrite them.

Comment: so is there a solution in either changing the munin plugin or reconfiguring ip_conntrack?

Comment: now i've seen the same behavior in other graphs... some value keeps increasing linear and the drops back to a normal level... i think this is either a bug in rdd or munin